# html/php no cache but keep cookies

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have a simple login page but i am having trouble displaying the logged in page. When the form is submitted, the same login page is displayed. I will have to click refresh or F5 before i can see the logged in page. I tried the no-cache (meta tag) but my problem is that the cookies are also gone (i couldn't store state).

By the way, my login uses redirect. The form submit calls a different page doing the validation and then redirects back to the same page but supposedly with different content (login form should not be there anymore).

I believe this is basic but unfortunately couldn't find an answer elsewhere.

Thanks.

Update:
Here are some codes:
Login page has ExtJs Form with submit:

```
login.getForm().getEl().dom.action='bridge.php/login';
login.getForm().getEl().dom.submit();
```

bridge.php is a rest client to another server:
snippet:

```
<?php
//echo $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PATH_INFO'];


require_once "RESTclient.php";
require_once "http_request.php";

$rest = new RESTclient();
$http_req = new httpRequest();

//$headers = $http_req->headers();
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
    if($key != "Cookie" && $key != "Content-Type"){
        unset($headers[$key]);
    }
}

//$headers["Content-Type"] = "";

$inputs = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
//$inputs = array_merge($inputs, $_);

$url = "http://another_server/rest_service_here";
$path = $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PATH_INFO'];
$server = $url.$path;

$rest->createRequest("$server",$http_req->method(),$inputs);
$rest->addHeaders($headers);
$rest->setBody($http_req->body());
$rest->sendRequest();

// get the headers now
$responseheaders = $rest->getResponseHeaders();
$responsecookies = $rest->getResponseCookies();

if ($responseheaders != null) {
    foreach ($responseheaders as $key => $value) {
        header($key.': '.$value);
    }
}
if ($responsecookies != null) {
    foreach ($responsecookies as $key => $value) {

        $name = $value['name'];
        $val = $value['value'];
        setcookie($name, $val);
    }
}
if($path=='/login') {
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Logging in</title>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/new_index.php">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
Redirecting to homepage...
</BODY>
</HTML>
    <?php 
} else {
    $output = $rest->getResponse();
    //$output = $output." ".$http_req->method();

    // start doing something about the output.
    //echo $http_req->body();
    //echo $http_req->raw();
    echo $output;
    //var_dump($headers);
}

?>
```

Comment: You might want to continue by showing the code for the login page, especially the branch that selects what to display.

Comment: I will try that but I will spend a little time summarizing it first. I will come back in a while. My login form is using ExtJs with standard submit style. The action url is a php that will display something like <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/index.php">. If uses caching, the index.php is redisplayed with the login form still there. F5 will display the correct display. If no-chache, cookies are gone and server cant know that the user has already logged in (means F5 keeps displaying the login form).

Comment: You should use the [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to re-direct directly from with PHP. See the Location re-direct example on the PHP manual page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're doing the following...

1. Always set/delete the login cookie before you output *anything*
2. Always re-direct *after* you've set the cookie. Ideally this should be to a page with a different URL (even if it's only a different query string), but failing that one that isn't cached *should* work fine.
3. As soon as you re-direct (via a `header('Location: ...');` call) end script processing via [exit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

..then all should be well. That said, as @Jon says post some code and we can take a look.

Comment: Thanks middaparka. I have to digest you answer first and then try it.

Comment: @demotics2002 The thing to realise if that without the exit, the code that follows a re-direct will still execute - it's just that the browser won't *necessarily* see it.

Comment: @demotics2002 No problem. Hope it all goes well. :-)